# Toggle Between Displaying the wireframe of an object in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to Unity and C# but have searched enough to deem that there is no solution currently available other than using a shader. (Shaders aren't available on the free version)

So far, I've been able to change whether my model is displayed in wireframe or not by using the following:

```
    // from http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL-wireframe.html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnPreRender() {
        GL.wireframe = true;
    }
    void OnPostRender() {
        GL.wireframe = false;
    }
}
```

However this doesn't let me toggle between the two in-game as required. I'm assuming the solution would be to re-render but not sure if this is the right approach. Any advice please?

Answer (score 3):

The only reasonable solution is to use shaders which *are* available in the free version. Since Unity 5, the pro and free versions are only different based on license; If your game makes over $100,000 USD, you need to pay for a pro license. However, all the features are available in both.

**UPDATE:** To actually apply the shader you need to make sure your model has been UV mapped (aka: unwrapping). This is a process that explains how to convert 2D texture coordinates to the 3D surface of the model. Think of it like how you would cut and fold wrapping paper around the surface of a gift.

Explaining UV mapping and unwrapping is vastly out of scope for this question. Here's a link explaining the basics in Blender

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics

Comment: Tried using a shader after reading that they didn't work without the paid version but it seems to be working. Now the issue is that I can't apply the shader because the model isn't 'un-wrapped' in blender? What can I do now?

Comment: This isn't supposed to be a discussion forum but I'll update my answer.